# delete multiple rows at once in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

i want to delete multiple rows at once from my matrix . In this case i want to delete row 0 ,1 and 2 by giving their index in the function numpy.delete

```
   import numpy as np
   matrice=[[2,3,5,6,8],[7,8,9,6,5],[5,8,8,8,9],[5,5,4,8,9]
   a=(0:2)
   matrice = np.delete(matrice, a, axis=0)
   print(matrice)
```

The problem is that np.delete only accepts as a seconde parameter the index of each row ,in my case i have to put in "a" : a=[0,1,2] but what should i do if i want to select 100 row!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a as a range (`range(3)` is equivalent to `[0, 1, 2]`):

```
import numpy as np
matrice=[[2,3,5,6,8],[7,8,9,6,5],[5,8,8,8,9],[5,5,4,8,9]]
a = range(3)
matrice = np.delete(matrice, a, axis=0)
print(matrice)
```

Other problems with your code: You did not close the list for matrice

Answer (score 0):

For selecting the rows/columns for deletion `np.delete` can accept slice objects, int, or array of ints. So try this:

```
a = slice(0, 3)
```

Or this:

```
a = range(0, 3)
```